# Is there any way to create a pdf file with the same content in two columns without typing two times in the editor?

Tags: pdf, multicolumn

I want to type question papers for students with less wastage of paper.
In Microsoft Word, first I type content in one column then paste that in the next column. So in one A4 paper, I will get two question papers. If I use the multiple column options in Latex, I need to type the same content twice right?. But is there any way to create a pdf file with the same content in two columns without typing two times in the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this by defining a command and calling it twice, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\quizquestions}{%

Stuff here

}

\quizquestions
\newpage
\quizquestions

\end{document}
```

If you're using the multicol package, use `\columnbreak` instead of `\newpage`.

And while I wouldn't recommend it, since you'd have to change both if you decided to make changes, copying and pasting is no harder in your LaTeX editor than it is in Word. ☺

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split the page to two equal columns, then you can do this by following TeX primitives:

```
\setbox0=\vbox{\hsize=.45\hsize
   here is the contents of the columns ...
}
\hbox to\hsize{\copy0\hss\box0}
```